# Benefits of ML in signal processing

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing

There is plenty of research on ML in signal processing. The majority of it, so it seams to me, is about showing feasibility of ML-based receivers (end-to-end or individual functional blocks of). To me, we are past that - pretty much everybody realizes that ML-based OFDM receiver is possible and can probably achieve comparable performance to that of a conventional receiver. Furthermore, even if/when someone manages to show some (probably marginal) performance gain, that would probably have academic value, but not much beyond that.

To me, there are two fundamental questions, for which I haven't found answers in the literature and would really appreciate some pointers:

1. Can ML-based receiver achieve comparable performance with comparable
   complexity (to these of a conventional receiver)?
2. Beyond (probably marginal) performance gains, what can be commercial
   benefits of switching from a conventional receiver to an ML-based
   one?

Thanks!

Comment: "what can be commercial benefits of switching from a conventional receiver to an ML-based one?" Marketability?

Comment: Looking for something more substantial, lol